# What cause my 404 error for my user_picture thumbnail in template file?

Tags: theming, 8, media

I want to print user_picture thumbnail in my page template. I am using the following code in `hook_preprocess_html()` in my .theme file.

```
$user = user_load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$style = entity_load('image_style', 'thumbnail');
$variables['user_picture'] = $style->buildUrl($user->get('user_picture')->entity->url());
```

It's generating a URl but it is showing 404, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Check whether URI is present is or not, or try to generate image url and pass to theme file with image tag

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy -  Url is there I want to make a thumbnail image from that URL

Comment: @zhilevan - What I'm trying to do is showing logined user image in my site header. I implemented hook_preprocess_html and trying to show rendered user_picture in a variable. is that the correct way for doing this ?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan yes, save current user image  url(or uri ) in  variable, and render it in template.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - off-topic question, why we are removing drupal 8 from the title of a question? if we can keep it there we will get better search result in google.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan : I just tried to help, but it seems you don't agree, so I restored your revision. For what it is worth: I think you should really improve the title of your question ... Have a look at the revision history for inspiration on that ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - See I'm new here, also I am not a native English speaker, so please correct my post. My point is if we keep drupal version in question titles it will help a lot when people search for something in google. Sometimes when I search for drupal 8 related stuff it will show for drupal 7 so I though it might help if we keep drupal version in title. Maybe I'm wrong :(

Comment: @Unnikrishnan : thank you for accepting my attempt to help. Not so long ago, I was also new here. I remember how tough it was to "get started", to (try to) respect the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (oeps: rules) of this site. And especially the unwritten rules, eg those that I noticed some moderators are applying. One of them **seems to be** that you don't include the drupal version in the title. Instead that is what the tag is about, if your question is drupal version specific. The site offers a lot of features about tags, you don't get via (eg) an 8 in the title. Makes sense?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan merci for taking my advice. If you want another one, I think you should change the title of your question to something like "Drupal 8 -  What cause my 404 error for my user_picture thumbnail in template file?" (= compromise between your google concern and my prior revision). It will probably help to illustrate why, IMO, your question is NOT a duplicate of the so called "possible duplicate". But, the choice is yours to yes/no do so.

Comment: What started as a question with a title which was, IMO, not appropriate, seems to have turned out in an interesting (popular?) question ... mostly after you seemed to have applied the compromise-title from my prior comment. Good for you! And thank you for accepting my recommendation. Keep in mind when you ask future questions: the title is as important as its content ... trust me.

Comment: We don't need _Drupal_ in the title, since this site is about Drupal. If you add it to all the questions, since they are all questions about Drupal, it becomes pretty useless. Also, we don't need tags in title, since those are visible in all the places where the questions are listed.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan : Remember "my" title recommendation from yesterday, in revision 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `hook_preprocess_html()` add the following code.

```
  $user = user_load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());;
  $variables['user_pic'] = $user->user_picture->entity->uri->value;
```

In your template file use code similar to the following one.

```
 <img width="62" height="62" class="image-responsive img-circle" src="{{ file_url(user.pic) }}" />
```

If you want to apply an image style, use the following code in `hook_preprocess_html()`.

```
$variables['user_pic'] = ImageStyle::load('thumbnail')->buildUrl($user->get('user_pic‌​ture')->entity->uri-‌​>value);
```

In the template file, use the following.

```
 <img src="{{ user.pic }}" />
```

Comment: ImageStyle::load('thumbnail')->buildUrl($user->get('user_picture')->entity->uri->value); 

This helped me thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load your file. In Drupal 8 everything is based on entities, and so are files. Loading a file is the same as loading a node.

```
$file = File::load($fid);
```

If your file is valid, you can start by building the render array for the image.
In the showed example, "thumbnail" is the used image style.

```
$variables = array(
  'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
  'uri' => $file->getFileUri(),
);

// The image.factory service will check if our image is valid.
$image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($file->getFileUri());
if ($image->isValid()) {
  $variables['width'] = $image->getWidth();
  $variables['height'] = $image->getHeight();
}
else {
  $variables['width'] = $variables['height'] = NULL;
}

$logo_render_array = [
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#width' => $variables['width'],
  '#height' => $variables['height'],
  '#style_name' => $variables['style_name'],
  '#uri' => $variables['uri'],
];
```

Comment: @A Ajay Kumar Reddy - I am looking for a rendered item not a renderable array here, What I'm trying to do is showing logined user image in my site header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510051/how-to-use-an-image-style-in-a-drupal-8-twig-template#answer-33669851

Then check this

Comment: @A Ajay Kumar Reddy - it is appending http://styles/thumbnail before my image path. This is what happening in my original code also.